# Vertical space between align and alignat environments

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical-alignment, align

I have a problem with the vertical space between `align` (1) and `alignat` (2). How can I reduce this space to the same vertical space as before (1)? How can I completely erase the vertical space? I know I can do this globally with `abovedisplayskip` and `belowdisplayskip`, but it doesn't work simply within these environments and I don't want to change anything globally.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}


\begin{document}
Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text
\begin{align}
X_{t+1} &=  \frac{Z_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_M}  \\
N_{t}  &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{T_{t+1}} \notag 
\end{align} 
% Reduce the vertical space here. Ideally to the same distance as from align to the above text, or whatever there is (eg other environments?)
\begin{alignat}{3}
&\text{as:} \quad & \gamma_{xyz} = \frac{a} {b} \qquad & \text{and}  & \qquad      \gamma_{zhk} = \frac{b}{a} \notag
\end{alignat}
Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is an undesired, too big vertical space between `align` and `alignat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't mess with it. It looks just fine if you put `as:` between the two environments:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text before.
\begin{align}
  X_{t+1} &= \frac{Z_{t+1} + X_{t+1}}{Y_{M}}\\
  N_{t}   &= \frac{X_{t+1} + X_{t+1}}{T_{t+1}}\notag
\end{align}
as
\begin{equation*}
  \gamma_{xyz} = \frac{a}{b}
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  \gamma_{zhk} = \frac{b}{a}
\end{equation*}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ok I assume the space is not easy to change then?

Comment: @TomM If you absolutely want to, you can just use `\vspace{<negative length>}` between the environments.

Answer (score 9):

when two separate display environments are set one after another, not separated by text,
the spacing between them is the sum of `\belowdisplayskip` and the following
`\abovedisplayskip`.  since both have quite a large amount of stretch, this usually
results in a much larger vertical space between them than desired.

it's better to combine them into a single `gather` environment, using subsidiary
display environments such as `aligned` and `alignedat` to structure the separate parts.
for example,

```
\begin{gather}
 \begin{aligned}
  X_{t+1} &=  \frac{Z_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_M}  \\
  N_{t}  &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{T_{t+1}}
 \end{aligned} \\[6pt]
 \begin{alignedat}{3}
  &\text{as:} \quad & \gamma_{xyz} = \frac{a} {b} \qquad & \text{and}
  & \qquad      \gamma_{zhk} = \frac{b}{a} \notag
 \end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
```

a little extra vertical space between the two parts (here `[6pt]`) can be added.

in this case, it's not even necessary to use `alignedat` -- just straightforward
math coding would suffice:

```
\text{as:\quad} \gamma_{xyz} = \frac{a}{b} \text{\qquad and\qquad}
                \gamma_{zhk} = \frac{b}{a}
```

even better would be to use `\intertext` for the initial text introducing that line:

```
\intertext{as:}
\gamma_{xyz} = \frac{a}{b} \text{\qquad and\qquad} \gamma_{zhk} = \frac{b}{a}
```

all within the enclosing `gather`.  if `\intertext` is used, don't add the optional
space between the parts; `\intertext` will take care of that.

Comment: This is a nice solution but if I have multiple labels within `aligned`, an error pops up: Multiple \label's: label x will be lost. I assume that is because of `gather`?

Comment: @TomM -- yes, `aligned` will provide only one label for the group.  `\intertext` (if appropriate) is the best approach in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem (with subequations as well), I used this:

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt}
```

Nothing else seemed to be working smoothly. (this is not perfect, but was the only thing I found that actually worked rather nicely). You can adjust the {1pt} values based on the layout and view that you have.
Just put it between aligns or alignats.

Comment: That's the content of what barbarabeeton already explained. And also the OP says he doesn't want to globally adjust those skips.

Comment: Yes, Barbara suggested _gather_. But if you have _subequations, you won't be able to use _gather_ as there is a conflict between _gather_ and _subequations_. Also, Barbara suggested to use some text, and again, you can't do anything if there's not text. I found this after several hours of testing and thought I would share (vertical spacing with subequations,align and alignat). Plus, if you put these two that I mentioned between _align_ and _alignat_ (inside the _subequations_), this is applied locally.

Comment: Does the OP use subequations?